# Resize images with javascript before assign them to an img tag

Tags: javascript, html, resize, image

I'm very very new on HTML and CSS development.

I have a HTML page with an `img` tag. This tag will hold some images. These images has different sizes. I set up a width and height to `img` tag using CSS.

All images will be shown using JavaScript.

May I need to resize images with JavaScript before I assign an image to `IMG` tag?
Maybe, I don't need to do that because I set up `IMG` size using CSS. Proportions will be constrained?

Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The aspect ratio wont be maintained if you have set both the height and width using css. But if you specify any one of the properties using the html `img` tag then the aspect ratio would be maintained.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. How can I resize an image before assign it to a `IMG` tag?

Comment: Do you want to maintain the aspect ratio? if yes then what would you like to be fixed? the height or the width?

Comment: @Coding-Freak: I have an `img` tag size = (260, 260). I have to fit any image in this size maintain the aspect ratio.

Comment: then you need to calculate the higher value in height and width, if the height is more than the width, then assign the `img` tag the property of height only with the value of 260, and vice versa.

Comment: JQuery is not a silver bullet. You have to carefully consider if you bring it into your toolchain.

Comment: @vansfannel: if its worth being correct, then please mark the tick back.

Answer (score 3):

You should do this on server side. With an administration script. You can create the versions of the original image when it is uploaded, then those images can be safely used by the HTML/CSS side.

This is not a task to do on the client side. Basically what you are doing here is to download a big image (lots of data) then dumb it down to create a smaller image. So you are wasting bandwindth of the client and bandwidth of the server.

If there is absolutely no ther possibility and you have a fixed area say 640x480, then you can acieve rudimentary cropping with maintaining ascpect ratio with the following:

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper"><img src="my.jpg"></div>
```

CSS:

```
#wrapper {
    width: 640px;
    height: 480px;
    line-height: 480px;
}

#wrapper img {
    width: 640px;
}
```

Comment: Better do to this on the server indeed. It's a waste to send a large image and make the client show a small image. If you resize it on the server, you can cache the resized images *and* you'll need less bandwidth to send the image. Both of which are a performance gain.

Comment: This is a good advice for anyone that wants to do this. But I'm going to use it on a WebWorks Playbook app.